# filename too long while executing shell script

Tags: linux, shell, comm

I am using below two commands in a shell script with files less than 100 lines and  I am getting ": File name too long" warning message while executing the script. When I ran through command line I am able to get the expected output .

functionality of below two commands are same,but when I tried with these I am getting same warning.

```
comm -2 -3 <$(sort -u dbfile_1.txt) <$(sort -u dbfile_hist) >> dbfile_hist

join -v 1 <$(sort -u dbfile_1.txt) <$(sort -u dbfile_hist) >> dbfile_hist
```

Could anyone help me out with this warning message.

Comment: Drop the `$` signs in both the commands. Just do `comm -2 -3 <(sort -u dbfile_1.txt) <(sort -u dbfile_hist)`

Comment: If I removed $ sign then it will throw "syntax error near unexpected token `('" error , do we have any alternative

Comment: What shell are you using? When I try this in bash, it works.

Comment: i am also using bash

Comment: Did you by accident add a blank space between a `<` and a `(`?

Comment: raj, is your script using `#!/bin/bash`, or do you invoke your script with `sh script.sh`? The latter is wrong because `<(...)` is bash-specific [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) syntax

Comment: Yes i am using #!/bin/bash